# returning to a uiviewcontroller without navigationcontroller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

my application has a UIViewController that isn't wrapped in a UINavigationController from it I call different UINavigationControllers each representing a state in a state machine.
calling these UINavigationControllers from code is done like this:

```
-(void) callState1
{
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    UINavigationController *state1NavigationController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"state1Navigation"];
    [self presentViewController:state1NavigationController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

in state1 there is a custom UIBarButtonItem representing the back control.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.backBtn;
```

Is there a native code that returns to the calling UIViewController?
or should I implement the same code from `callState1` in the back button calling the UIViewController, and if so how can I synchronize the data between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are presenting the view controller (state1NavigationController) modally, you need to use the method *dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:* to dismiss the state1NavigationController and go back.

Comment: does calling dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion aside from closing the NavigationViewController will also return me to the UIView, if not how do I go back? also how do I synchronize the data?

Comment: Basically it will dismiss whatever view controller that you present modally and return you the original view controller that present it. You can sync the data with delegate or singleton.